# Where in Austria can I exchange Swiss Francs to Euros?

Tags: money, exchange, austria

My daughter bought Swiss francs and she didn't spend it all, now she is in Austria, where can she change the Swiss francs (CHF) to Euros (EUR)?

Comment: Depending on the amount, simply try any bank, the larger ones are better. They won't change 5 CHF, but if there is more, they will do it.

Comment: Any bank or currency exchange place should do it. Probably worth visiting a few though, as they'll likely have slightly different rates, and may well have different rules on minimum amount to change, if coins are accepted etc

Answer (score 3):

You should try any big banks! they will be able to do it. If you have the receipt of purchase for those Francs (I doubt it), it will be a plus as it clearly shows that you probably have done it for travel purposes.

I am not sure about the Weschels (Cambio/Bureau De Change). If the shop is too small, they might not have the CHF to Euro/USD/GBP facility. Try bank or a hot touristy spot. Airport should be the ideal place if everywhere else turns out to be blank.